# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:

Tags: .net

When is this exception thrown. Can anybody help me to resolve this!

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.79.1.155:50912     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapTcpConnection.Connect()     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapTcpConnection..ctor(Uri remoteEndpoint, SoapTcpTransportOptions options, ISoapFormatter formatter)     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapTcpTransport.CreateConnection(Uri transportAddress)     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapTcpTransport.GetConnection(Uri destination)     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapTcpOutputChannel.Send(SoapEnvelope message)     at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging.SoapSender.Send(SoapEnvelope envelope)     at Manh.ILS.General.WSEHelper.Send(Session sess, String requestURI, String responseURI, String action, Object messageBody)     at CLASSWS.Receive(SoapEnvelope envelope)

Comment: What part of this don't you understand? The remote service isn't running, or else a firewall is preventing it from being reached.

Answer (score 0):

Either your server program did not open this port or you have not opened the firewall for the port number 50912.

If you are trying to run this on a localhost, the server program may be executing on the 127.0.0.1 ip but you are trying with 10.79.1.155. Try to change the target ip to 127.0.0.1 and check.